# Java GUI unable to automatically run on website

Tags: java, html, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a Java program that runs a GUI that receives required information from the user/displays information.  There is a button in the GUI that generates a Proposal in the form of a PDF that I wish the user to be able to download.  I am having trouble having the GUI automatically run when the web page is opened, instead it just displays the icon of the JNLP file being referenced within the HTML.

Comment: Modern versions of java do not support java web start

Comment: Then how would I go about having my GUI run on a webpage?  Currently I am able to have the website display the file but not run it within an iframe.  I appreciate your input!

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up terms about what happens where. Consider explaining this better in your question.

Comment: Very possible, I am learning HTML for this project alone.  I have a java program that runs a GUI and reads from multiple text files/pdfs.  This program's end goal is to generate a pdf for the user to download.  My goal is for the webpage to automatically display the GUI and generate a PDF based off of user input.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) does *not* run a GUI within a web page. Java Web Start is a technology for downloading and launching a *local* Java app on a [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) already present on the user’s machine.

Java Web Start has been phased out by Oracle, as Oracle no longer expects user machines to have a JVM pre-installed. See Oracle white paper, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf).

[*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/) is an alternative open-source implementation of Java Web Start technology.

If you want to build a web app GUI using pure Java without having to learn HTML, JavaScript, DOM, WebSockets, etc., I suggest [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow).